# AJAX Vanilla JavaScript - sending a 2cnd async post only after the 1st has been sent

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making a HotSpot which gives you access to the internet once you have input your email address.

For this to work, I need to make two seperate AJAX posts.

- The 1st one sends (hidden) username and password to the router (which gives the user internet access).
- The 2cnd sends the input mail to the database (for which it needs interent access)

The problem is, that I'm getting a warning* if setting async to false (instead of true).

`xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', false);`

Warning*: *Synchronus XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated becouse of its detrimental effects to the end user's experiance. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org.*

To sum it up. I guess I need to make two async AJAX POSTs (as sync gives me the warning), and the 2cnd one (email), should only be sent after the 1st one (username, password) has been sent.

The problem I'm currently having, is that sometimes the mail gets inserted into the DB and sometimes it doesn't. I also don't want to set a huge setTimeout for the user to get redirected.

```
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="mail" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="mail">
        <h1>Hotspot</h1>
        <h2>To gain internet access, enter your email.</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);
    function SendAjax() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(email);
        // Check if field is empty 
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email.");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var xhr2= new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                    var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
                    setTimeout(function (){
                        location.href="http://server/redirected.html";}
                        ), 1000
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Posting a snippet of a possible solution. It currently isn't working as expected, posting it so we can discuss possible issues in more detail.

```
document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);
    function SendAjax() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(email);
        // Check if fields are empty 
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email.");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                if (this.readyState === DONE){
                    var xhr2= new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                    var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
                    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    var DONEDONE = this.DONEDONE || 4;
                        if (this.readyState === DONEDONE){
                            location.href="http://server/redirected.html";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried this option and it "doesn't work". Computer does eventually get internet access (about 8 sec), the "user" is redirected immediately and the email isn't saved in the database (even after the revisions).

I would like to thank everyone for the help you have given so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've always tried to stay away from JS, so I don't really know what options I have. I'll read up on it.

Comment: Why not use async and do your second call in the callback of the first one?

Comment: it is async. how would i make a 2cnd call in the callback of the 1st one? could you give me a quick example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck resolving the issue with basic AJAX, so I used Async / Await and Promises to eventually make it work.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

The code:

```
document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", sendAjax);

function resolveAfter05Second() {
  console.log("starting fast promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("fast")
      console.log("fast promise is done")
    }, 500)
  })
}

async function sendAjax() {
    let ax1 = await Ajax1 ("POST", "http://router/login")
    let fast = await resolveAfter05Second()
    let ax2 = await Ajax2 ("POST", "http://webserver/anti-xss.php")
}

function Ajax1 (method, url){
    return new Promise (function (resolve,  reject){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300){
                resolve(xhr.response);
                console.log("Success!");
                console.log("You'r logged in.");
                console.log("XHR1 " + xhr.readyState);
                console.log("XHR1 " + xhr.status);
            }else{
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (){
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.send("username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
    });
}

function Ajax2 (method, url){
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
        let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr2.open('POST', 'http://webserver/anti-xss.php', true);
        xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr2.onload = function(){
            if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300){
                resolve(xhr2.response);
                console.log("Success!");
                console.log("You'r email is " + useremail + ".");
                console.log("XHR2 " + xhr2.readyState);
                console.log("XHR2 " + xhr2.status);
            }else{
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr2.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr2.onerror = function (){
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: this.statusText
            });
        };
        let useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;                 
        xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two options, firstone is to define a XHR event handler:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
  if (this.readyState === DONE){
    ... make here the second request (xhr2) ...
    ... timeouts not needed ...
  }
}
```

Like described, for example, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_onreadystatechange_event_listener Timeouts are not longer needed as long as the event will trigger when request is completely done.

The other option is simpler: change from async mode to sync. This will block the interface, so is less prefered usually. Change to false here:

```
xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', false);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the 1st bit of code. I'll try and stay away from 'true' since it gives me the warning...

Comment: You mean stay away from 'false' for making it async? With 'true' it should not show that warning, only if you specify 'false'. I'm going to edit your question.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention to remove the timeouts if you use the callback, as long as they are no longer needed.

Comment: And also you can detect errors, like not authorized error in the event handler.

Comment: I've tried the 1st option and it "doesn't work". Computer does eventually get internet acces, the "user" is redirected immediately and the email isn't saved in the database. I'm going to edit my question, to show you what I have done (and so you can point out if I fcked something up)

Comment: to clarify, I know setting it as false works, but it's giving me the warning, and since it's depricated I would like to avoid it. if there will be no other "simple" solution I might still use it

Answer (score 1):

You set the location of the document right after making the second ajax call.

You should listen to the readystate of your second ajax request as well.
Once that is 'done' you can set the location of the document.

```
function SendAjax() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    console.log(email);
    // Check if fields are empty 
    if (email=="") {
        alert("Please enter your email.");
    }
    // AJAX code to submit form
    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));

                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr2.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The snippet of your 'possible solution' is almost there, just attach to the onreadystatechange event like you do in you first ajax call

Comment: edited it, still the same problem (email isn't saved in the DB)

Comment: The code to set the location is executed when the second ajax call is successfully executed. So imo you need to inspect the insertDB.php code in order to see why the  email address isn't saved.
On the other hand, why are you making two requests? Isn't it possible to save the email during the first call?

Comment: router and the DBserver aren't the same machine or even on the same network. I need a) internet access to b) send email to DB. insertDB.php works, it's already been tried.

Comment: @DrDoom, I edited by adding code, have a look at it

Comment: nothing changed. still the same. thanks for the help though. it's wierd... it whould work...